# how to resolve the error reference binding to null pointer of type value

Tags: c++

```
 //this is my code that i have written 
vector<vector<int>> generate(int numRows) {

        vector<vector<int>>ans;

        ans[0].push_back(1);
        if(numRows==1) return ans;

        ans[1].push_back(1);
        ans[1].push_back(1);

        if(numRows==2) return ans;

        for(int i=2;i<=numRows-1;i++){
            for(int j=0 ; j<= ans [i] . size() - 2 ; j++){

                int x= ans [i][j] + ans [i][j+1];
                ans [i+1].push_back(x);
            }
            ans [i+1].insert(ans [i+1].begin(),1);
            ans [i+1].insert(ans [i+1].end(),1);
        }

        return ans;
}
```

this code showing below error.

```
Line 1034: Char 9: runtime error: reference binding to null pointer of type 'std::vector<int, std::allocator<int>>' (stl_vector.h)
SUMMARY: UndefinedBehaviorSanitizer: undefined-behavior /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../../include/c++/9/bits/stl_vector.h:1043:9
```

Comment: `ans` is empty when you try to evaluate `ans[0]` and `ans[1]`. There is no element 0 or element 1 yet. You need to insert elements into it first.

Comment: And then something fun will happen at `int x= ans [i][j] + ans [i][j+1];`  What are you trying to do? I think the problem of the code is not just in that line.

Answer (score 1):

As `vector` stores data on heap internally which can grow and shrink based on your usage. But in your case, you made an empty `vector` so it did not allocate any memory. To avoid this error you have to provide size to vector constructor or push back empty vector on every index you want to use.
so you might want to do this:

```
    std::vector<vector<int>> ans(numRows);
    ans[0].push_back(1);
```

This will work.